# spring authentication entry point

Tags: spring, security

I have controller method, which annotated with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someting")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ACTIVE')")
...
```

When users without it role transit on this mapping I want to make the users without the appropriate role of the redirect to the home page and displays an alert, the fact that access is denied.

To solve this problem I make custom AccessDeniedHandler, which works perfectly, but only for authenticated users

For users without authentication I found AuthenticationEntryPoint
It looks like

```
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                     HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                     AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        FlashMap flashMap = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(httpServletRequest);
        if(flashMap != null) {
            Alerts.addWarningAlert(flashMap, "access denied");
        }
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/");
    }

}
```

My alert can be added only to flash attributes or model of my main page, but flash map in this method always have null value

How I can solve it without redirecting to other controller, which then redirects to main page and add value to model? Or can I add my flash attributes to http servlet response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible using Session attributes. I added attribute and then take this attribute from Session in alerts handler.